# Handling user interaction - Click Button message is not like documented

Tags: slack-api

I'm experimenting ways to allow users to interact with my app through Slack.
So far, I was able to create a Home App, so that when the user clicks on the app it displays a neat page, with formatted text, images, and some action buttons (built with Block Kit).

What I am not being able to do is handling the user interactions, specifically when the user clicks one of the buttons. I got Slack to invoke my app's API, but the message I receive is absolutely nothing to do with the documentation.

On Slack, I set up Interactivity & Shortcuts, sending all requests to `https://slack-interaction-sample.xpto.com/slack/v1/actions`.

I then send a message to Slack, using Block Kit, containing a simple button:

```
"blocks": [
              {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                  "type": "mrkdwn",
                  "text": `*JT*\nBackend Developer @ ${  currentTime  }`
                },
                "accessory": {
                  "type": "image",
                  "image_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/fb/b5/b6/fbb5b6798f31538f2497e7ceb2b52674.jpg",
                  "alt_text": "JT"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "actions",
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                      "type": "plain_text",
                      "text": "Do Stuff",
                      "emoji": true
                    },
                    "style": "primary",
                    "value": "doStuff"
                  }
                ]
              }
]
```

This message is correctly displayed on Slack. When I click the button, Slacks sends a request to the configured URL and, on my nodejs instance, the following code is executed:

```
app.post("/slack/v1/actions", function(req, res) {
  console.log("**********************************************************");
  console.log("/slack/v1/actions");
  console.log("**********************************************************");
  console.log("Request: %s",req);

  res.status(200);
  res.json({});
  console.log("**********************************************************");
});
```

According to Slack's documentation (`https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling`), I should be getting a `payload` parameter with something like this:

```
[
  {
    "action_id": "action-id-0",
    "block_id": "/RXP",
    "text": {
      "type": "plain_text",
      "text": "Ask",
      "emoji": true
    },
    "value": "approve",
    "style": "primary",
    "type": "button",
    "action_ts": "1588254893.249857"
  }
]
```

Instead, what I get is this:

```
IncomingMessage {
   _readableState: [ReadableState],
   readable: true,
   _events: [Object: null prototype],
   _eventsCount: 1,
   _maxListeners: undefined,
   socket: [Socket],
   connection: [Socket],
   httpVersionMajor: 1,
   httpVersionMinor: 1,
   httpVersion: '1.1',
   complete: false,
   headers: [Object],
   rawHeaders: [Array],
   trailers: {},
   rawTrailers: [],
   aborted: false,
   upgrade: false,
   url: '/slack/v1/actions',
   method: 'POST',
   statusCode: null,
   statusMessage: null,
   client: [Socket],
   _consuming: false,
   _dumped: false,
   next: [Function: next],
   baseUrl: '',
   originalUrl: '/slack/v1/actions',
   _parsedUrl: [Url],
   params: {},
   query: {},
   res: [ServerResponse],
   body: {},
   route: [Route],
   [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}:
´´´

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. That does not look like a response from Slack. Please add your code, so people can help you better find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Erik! Thanks for the warm welcome. I edited the original message and added the details you asked. Thank you for your help! - Jorge